# Howto resolve a function name conflict when compiling a kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to compile a 3rd party kernel module for RHEL 5.6 and it is failing due to function name conflicts with `mutex_acquire` and `mutex_release`.  This kernel module compiles cleanly on RHEL 4.7 so something changed between kernels 2.6.9 and 2.6.18.  Sadly, this kernel module is no longer supported by the vendor but I do have the source code for `mutex.c` and `mutex.h` which define these functions.  Unfortunately there is an object file `nivxi.o` upon which no source code is distributed and this object file is calling `mutex_acquire` and `mutex_release` so I cannot just simply alter their names.

As an aside, I originally attempted to just modify the names slightly and the compile errors went away but when it went to make the .ko kernel module it complained that it couldn't find `mutex_acquire` or `mutex_release`; presumably due to `nivxi.o`

How do I force the compiler/linker to use the function definitions in my local .c/.h files even though they trounce over like-named functions elsewhere?

#### mutex.h

```
NIVXICC void mutex_acquire(mutex_t *mutex);
NIVXICC void mutex_release(mutex_t *mutex);
```

#### nivxicc.h (just incase this is pertinent)

```
#ifndef NIVXICC_H
#define NIVXICC_H
#define NIVXICC __attribute__((regparm(0))) __attribute__((cdecl))
#endif
```

#### /usr/include/lockdep.h (conflicting definition)

```
#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC
# ifdef CONFIG_PROVE_LOCKING
#  define mutex_acquire(l, s, t, i)             lock_acquire(l, s, t, 0, 2, i)
# else
#  define mutex_acquire(l, s, t, i)             lock_acquire(l, s, t, 0, 1, i)
# endif
# define mutex_release(l, n, i)                 lock_release(l, n, i)
#else
# define mutex_acquire(l, s, t, i)              do { } while (0)
# define mutex_release(l, n, i)                 do { } while (0)
#endif
```

#### Error

```
# make
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.18-238.el5/build SUBDIRS=/usr/local/nivxi/src KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-238.el5-i686'
test -e include/linux/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (            \
        echo;                                                           \
        echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";               \
        echo "         include/linux/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";      \
        echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
        echo;                                                           \
        /bin/false)
mkdir -p /usr/local/nivxi/src/.tmp_versions
rm -f /usr/local/nivxi/src/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/usr/local/nivxi/src
gcc -m32 -Wp,-MD,/usr/local/nivxi/src/.vxi.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem \
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/include -D__KERNEL__ -Iinclude \
-include include/linux/autoconf.h -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes \
-Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Wstrict-prototypes \
-Wundef -Werror-implicit-function-declaration \
-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -fwrapv -Os -pipe -msoft-float \
-fno-builtin-sprintf -fno-builtin-log2 -fno-builtin-puts \
-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2  -march=i686 -mtune=generic -mtune=generic \
-mregparm=3 -ffreestanding -Iinclude/asm-i386/mach-generic \
-Iinclude/asm-i386/mach-default -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-stack-protector \
-Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -DVXI_MAJOR=0 \
-DREMAP_PAGE_RANGE_VMA -D__DEBUG__ -DMODULE -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" \
-D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(vxi)" -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vximod)" \
-c -o /usr/local/nivxi/src/.tmp_vxi.o /usr/local/nivxi/src/vxi.c

    In file included from /usr/local/nivxi/src/vxi.c:13:
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/mutex.h:59:42: error: macro "mutex_acquire" requires 4 arguments, but only 1 given
    In file included from /usr/local/nivxi/src/vxi.c:13:
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/mutex.h:59: warning: ‘regparm’ attribute only applies to function types
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/mutex.h:59: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute only applies to function types
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/mutex.h:61:42: error: macro "mutex_release" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/mutex.h:61: warning: ‘regparm’ attribute only applies to function types
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/mutex.h:61: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute only applies to function types
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/vxi.c:128:31: error: macro "mutex_acquire" requires 4 arguments, but only 1 given
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/vxi.c:133:31: error: macro "mutex_release" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/vxi.c:146:31: error: macro "mutex_acquire" requires 4 arguments, but only 1 given
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/vxi.c:158:31: error: macro "mutex_release" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/vxi.c: In function ‘vxi_mmap’:
    /usr/local/nivxi/src/vxi.c:243: error: implicit declaration of function ‘remap_page_range’
    make[2]: *** [/usr/local/nivxi/src/vxi.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/local/nivxi/src] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-238.el5-i686'
    make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: Rename nivxicc's mutex functions (and doing so across its entire source, not just the .h file) and that should do it.

Comment: @user can't, see last sentence of 1st paragraph and all of 2nd paragraph of my Question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem will not be in your object file as macros have file-scope and are replaced by the preprocessor.  Thus after being compiled, the macro no longer exists as far as your `nivxi.o` file is concerned.

The issue is probably in your `mutex.h` file.  I would look at the top and you will likely see an `#include <lockdep.h>` line. Thus once the preprocessor gets down to your function definition, it treats `mutex_acquire` as a token to be replaced (with the wrong number of arguments).

The easiest way to solve your problem will be to `#undef mutex_acquire` and `#undef mutex_release` at the beginning of `mutex.h`.  This will prevent the preprocessor from replacing the tokens in your `mutex.h`.  Since defines have file-scope, you don't need to worry about this propagating beyond your application

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, an `#undef CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC` won't work because you'll notice the `#else` clause that still defines a `mutex_acquire` and `mutex_release` regardless.  Also, although these are macro's in the `<linux/lockdep.h>` header, they are first-class function declarations in "mutex.h" which is why `nivxi.o` has them linked in and is complaining.  The only kludge fix I've found so far is to alter `<linux/lockdep.h>` and wrap that macro block with `#ifndef NOLOCKDEP` and then issue `-DNOLOCKDEP` as a compiler flag.

Comment: Ah, I missed the nested defines.  I've edited the solution above.  This should keep your modifications contained to within your module

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick without having to alter the `<linux/lockdep.h>` header